# python path/ Pip install

Tags: python, path, pip, sys

I am having issues with a new install of `pip`.  I'm getting the following error:

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 123]
>   The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect:
>   'C:\Python;C:'

I'm running `Python 3.7.1` from `C:\Python` directory.

I've added the `path`:

> C:\Users\randy\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\randy\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\randy\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Python;C:\Python\Scripts;

Could this be the problem? Does it seem I have `DLLs` and `lib` off the root?

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path

['', 'C:\\Python', 'C:\\Python\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python\\Doc', 'C:\\Python\\include', 'C:\\Python\\Lib', 'C:\\Python\\libs', 'C:\\Python\\Scripts', 'C:\\Python\\tcl', 'C:\\Python\\Tools', 'C:\\Python\\python37.zip', 'C:\\DLLs', 'C:\\lib']
```

Comment: write the syntax by which you have added the path.

Comment: I changed the path using the environment variables (Windows) and the text output is above. I don't where the incorrect: 'C:\Python;C:' is.  Maybe in pip install?

Comment: It seems that this is still an issue. [link](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11451) . There is some path which contains spaces in them.

Comment: I started with a fresh install of python 3.7.3, then pycharm.  I removed everything from the Path before the installs, hoping PyCharm would add to path.  I didn't, and I am still getting the same error.  It seems that get-pip.py is referencing an old environment or something?  Any ideas?

Comment: The document says that pip [pip doc](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) is already installed if you are using Python 2>=2.7.9 or Python 3>=3.4. Since you have already installed 3.7.3, pip should be there. Try to run the command of pip directly.